# Copied this SQL code from class and it won't run. I'm attempting to use JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Error message says "unrecognizable at 10:3"

```
SELECT
  employees.name AS employee_name,
  employees.role AS employee_role,
  depatments.name AS department_name
FROM
  `strategic-volt-320816.employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN
  `strategic-volt-320816.employee_data.departments`
ON
  employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: Because you have left out table aliases.

Comment: Strange... we haven't learned about those in my class yet. It seemed to run fine for my instructor without aliases.

Comment: No, the code did not run for your instructor.  It just won't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the tables aliases:

```
SELECT
  employees.name AS employee_name,
  employees.role AS employee_role,
  depatments.name AS department_name
FROM
  `strategic-volt-320816.employee_data.employees` employees
INNER JOIN
  `strategic-volt-320816.employee_data.departments` departments
ON
  employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: Ok Thank you. We haven't learned about aliases in class yet. Frustrating that they would give us code missing that and expect it to somehow work for us.